# Many Applications accessing obsolete x509anchors

Tags: macos, error, console, certificate

When I look into console.app I see that every 2 minutes one of the mac os programs (Safari, Mail, Keychain, Addressbook, WebProcess etc.) is giving an "Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors." error. How do I solve this problem?

```
Systeminfo:

Mac OS 10.6.8
```

[image: Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors.]

Comment: Have you deleted any certificates from your Keychain? Or added any new Root level certificates?

Comment: This has been a long time ago, I just don't know :( But I have been looking at the X509Anchors Keychain and saw that there are 6 non trusted certificates in it, for example "Free SSL Certification Authority"

Answer (score 2):

Did you perhaps upgrade from an earlier version of OS X? Apparently [this error is benign:](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/x509anchors.html)

> The X509Anchors keychain is harmless and can be left in place. If you do not use any third-party software that requires this keychain, it can be deleted.