# My Active Directory account keeps locking me out

Tags: macos, accounts, active-directory

I have a Mac Pro on Yosemite and I only use Active Directory when accessing server folders and my email.  My account locks me out regularly and I can't seem to figure out why.  I have disabled all devices except my computer and hoping someone here can help me determine what is going on. My help desk here can't seem to help.

Here is part of my recent system.log file.

```
Feb 17 10:40:01 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com Microsoft Entourage[378]: Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors.
Feb 17 10:40:33 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Feb 17 10:41:08 justins-mac-pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Feb 17 10:41:12 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com Microsoft Entourage[378]: Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors.
Feb 17 10:43:01 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com CalendarAgent[291]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
Feb 17 10:43:31 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 17 10:45:52 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com launchservicesd[57]: Application App:"loginwindow" asn:0x0-1001 pid:73 refs=7 @ 0x7ff4b1702280 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontApps ( ( "LSApplication:0x0-0xc30c3 pid=1021 "ScreenSaverEngine"")), so denying. : LASSession.cp #1521 SetFrontApplication() q=LSSession 100006/0x186a6 queue
Feb 17 10:45:52 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com WindowServer[166]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to loginwindow, psn 0x0-0x1001, securitySessionID=0x186a6, err=-13066
Feb 17 10:45:52 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com launchservicesd[57]: Application App:"loginwindow" asn:0x0-1001 pid:73 refs=8 @ 0x7ff4b1702280 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontApps ( ( "LSApplication:0x0-0xc30c3 pid=1021 "ScreenSaverEngine"")), so denying. : LASSession.cp #1521 SetFrontApplication() q=LSSession 100006/0x186a6 queue
Feb 17 10:45:52 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com WindowServer[166]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to loginwindow, psn 0x0-0x1001, securitySessionID=0x186a6, err=-13066
Feb 17 10:45:53 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com loginwindow[73]: ERROR | -[LWBuiltInScreenLockAuthLion closeAuthAndReset:] | Attempted to remove an observer when not observing
Feb 17 10:47:07 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: considerRebuildOfPrelinkedKernel prebuild rebuild has expired
Feb 17 10:48:18 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: ### ERROR: Exit sniff failed (probably already unsniffed) (err=10)
Feb 17 10:48:21 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com bluetoothaudiod[739]: Device didn't respond to an A2DP command
Feb 17 10:48:29 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: [0xffffff804a532200][clientClose]
Feb 17 10:48:29 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: [0xffffff804a532200][free]()
Feb 17 10:48:29 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: [0xffffff8042bb5200][free]()
Feb 17 10:48:29 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: [0xffffff804bd95400][free]()
Feb 17 10:48:29 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: [0xffffff804de3d600][free]()
Feb 17 10:48:34 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: LPAudioEngine[0xffffff8031ff1800]::performAudioEngineStart()
Feb 17 10:48:36 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: LPAudioEngine[0xffffff8031ff1800]::performAudioEngineStop()
Feb 17 10:50:20 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80533ae690) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80533ae690, region 0x7fff8ce00000->0x7fff8d000000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Feb 17 10:50:20 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803b809000) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803b809000, region 0x7fff8ce00000->0x7fff8d000000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Feb 17 10:50:50 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 17 10:51:11 justins-mac-pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Feb 17 10:51:15 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com CoreServicesUIAgent[336]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff74747c60> { count = 1, contents =
        "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff74747f70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
    }>
Feb 17 10:51:15 justins-mac-pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Safari.82960[1081]): Service exited due to signal: Terminated: 15
Feb 17 10:51:21 justins-mac-pro Console[644]: assertion failed: 14C109: libxpc.dylib + 24736 [876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107]: 0x13
Feb 17 10:51:21 justins-mac-pro Console[644]: assertion failed: 14C109: libxpc.dylib + 40320 [876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107]: 0x13
Feb 17 10:51:21 --- last message repeated 2505 times ---
Feb 17 10:51:21 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8035939c30) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8035939c30, region 0x7fff8ce00000->0x7fff8d000000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Feb 17 10:51:21 justins-mac-pro Console[644]: assertion failed: 14C109: libxpc.dylib + 40320 [876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107]: 0x13
Feb 17 10:51:22 --- last message repeated 3141 times ---
Feb 17 10:51:22 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80533ae2d0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80533ae2d0, region 0x7fff8ce00000->0x7fff8d000000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Feb 17 10:51:22 justins-mac-pro Console[644]: assertion failed: 14C109: libxpc.dylib + 40320 [876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107]: 0x13
Feb 17 10:51:22 --- last message repeated 1315 times ---
Feb 17 10:51:22 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80533ae2d0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80533ae2d0, region 0x7fff8ce00000->0x7fff8d000000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
Feb 17 10:51:22 justins-mac-pro Console[644]: assertion failed: 14C109: libxpc.dylib + 40320 [876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107]: 0x13
Feb 17 10:51:29 --- last message repeated 32446 times ---
Feb 17 10:51:29 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com Google Chrome Helper[1091]: CoreText CopyFontsForRequest received mig IPC error (FFFFFFFFFFFFFECC) from font server
Feb 17 10:51:29 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 17 10:51:29 justins-mac-pro Console[644]: assertion failed: 14C109: libxpc.dylib + 40320 [876216DC-D5D3-381E-8AF9-49AE464E5107]: 0x13
Feb 17 10:51:42 --- last message repeated 62773 times ---
Feb 17 10:51:42 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com Console[644]: Application com.apple.Safari never opened its Services port before the timeout.
Feb 17 10:55:05 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com mds[36]: CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 1. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
Feb 17 10:55:09 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Copied 1306 items (13.9 GB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 7935.
Feb 17 10:55:10 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com distnoted[1099]: # distnote server agent  absolute time: 8961.253119447   civil time: Tue Feb 17 10:55:10 2015   pid: 1099 uid: 89  root: no
Feb 17 10:55:20 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Copied 7 items (234 bytes) from volume Media Drive. Linked 35.
Feb 17 10:55:23 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Created new backup: 2015-02-17-105523
Feb 17 10:55:24 justins-mac-pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Feb 17 10:55:25 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk1s3
Feb 17 10:55:25 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com fseventsd[21]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
Feb 17 10:55:25 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com mds[36]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fe9ee8a1e00 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
Feb 17 10:55:26 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Copying OS X Recovery set
Feb 17 10:55:42 justins-mac-pro kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk1s3
Feb 17 10:55:42 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Starting post-backup thinning
Feb 17 10:57:15 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd-helper[46]: Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
Feb 17 10:58:11 justins-mac-pro com.apple.iCloudHelper[1113]: objc[1113]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Feb 17 10:58:11 justins-mac-pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Feb 17 10:58:13 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 17 10:58:13 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com AddressBookSourceSync[1111]: [CardDAVPlugin-ERROR] error retrieving image for url:https://tex%40prod21.com@p02-contacts.icloud.com/90944610/wcs/01389d7119a847529777557e089f83bc4f9ea7ea87 Error Domain=CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain error 404.)" UserInfo=0x7ff4201eaf90 {CoreDAVHTTPHeaders=<CFBasicHash 0x7ff4201e94f0 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
    entries =>
        0 : X-Responding-Instance = <CFString 0x7ff4201afd50 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{contents = "carddav:10200601:st11p02me-carddav006:8001:15A72:162735"}
        1 : Retry-After = 10800
        3 : Content-Length = 0
        5 : X-Apple-Request-UUID = <CFString 0x7ff4200d3ba0 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{contents = "ddbae8b5-3c34-420f-a3c1-597e6bf99477"}
        6 : Date = <CFString 0x7ff42002a580 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{contents = "Tue, 17 Feb 2015 16:58:13 GMT"}
    }
    }
Feb 17 10:58:13 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com AddressBookSourceSync[1111]: [CardDAVPlugin-ERROR] error retrieving image for url:https://tex%40prod21.com@p02-contacts.icloud.com/90944610/wcs/01389d7119a847529777557e089f83bc4f9ea7ea87 Error Domain=CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain error 404.)" UserInfo=0x7ff420727420 {CoreDAVHTTPHeaders=<CFBasicHash 0x7ff420724f80 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
    entries =>
        0 : X-Responding-Instance = <CFString 0x7ff41b11b430 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{contents = "carddav:10200101:st11p02me-carddav001:8001:15A72:162735"}
        1 : Retry-After = 10800
        3 : Content-Length = 0
        5 : X-Apple-Request-UUID = <CFString 0x7ff41b135a30 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{contents = "155c5f7d-5f14-4b86-b33d-7658533be211"}
        6 : Date = <CFString 0x7ff41b159a80 [0x7fff74b6bcf0]>{contents = "Tue, 17 Feb 2015 16:58:13 GMT"}
    }
    }
Feb 17 10:58:44 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Deleted /Volumes/MP TimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/Justin’s Mac Pro/2015-01-18-002240 (594 MB)
Feb 17 10:59:35 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Deleted /Volumes/MP TimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/Justin’s Mac Pro/2015-02-15-233743 (487.5 MB)
Feb 17 10:59:50 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com Microsoft Entourage[378]: Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors.
Feb 17 10:59:52 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com com.apple.backupd[603]: Deleted /Volumes/MP TimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/Justin’s Mac Pro/2015-02-15-223451 (492.4 MB)
Feb 17 11:00:00 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com SubmitDiagInfo[1116]: Triggering diganostics messages cleanup
```

Comment: Ok, reading he log :) If one ignores all the non relevant info like Audio, Backup, AddressBook, Calenda, one is left with Google Chrome He acting up, and the Microsoft Entourage (email program). For time been disable the Backup process and kill the Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an [obsolete X509Anchors keychain](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/x509anchors.html) item.

This problem is also discussed on StackExchange [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40013/many-applications-accessing-obsolete-x509anchors).

The key line here is:

> Feb 17 10:59:50 justins-mac-pro.dtn.com Microsoft Entourage[378]:
>   Warning: accessing obsolete X509Anchors.

This Apple Support Community posting [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1274386) discusses this issue with a possible solution.

The Office Mac Help site also [discusses](http://www.office.mvps.org/faq_topic/leopard.html) (#5) this problem, too, with another possible solution.

Comment: Thank you I will give that a try... sorry I guess I should have filtered it out a bit but wasn't sure what could be causing it and just copied around the time it locked.